# Listview has been removed from react native error after adding react-native-gridview

Tags: react-native

I have installed `react-native-gridview` and after that I am getting this error.

[image]

The line number shown in error is `Media.js:134`. It contains the following code.

```
<GridView data={this.state.dataList} itemsPerRow={2}
    renderItem={(item) => {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#8F8', borderWidth: 1, margin: 8 }}>
                <Image style={styles.imageThumbnail} source={{ uri: item.path}} />
            </View>
        );
    }}/>
```

I can't understand why I am getting this error. I am not using any `ListView`

Please Help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that **`react-native-gridview`** is using Listview in their library as you can see [here](https://github.com/jskuby/react-native-gridview#react-native-gridview).

> And now react-native stopped giving support to [Listviews](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html), rather now you
>   can use [FlatList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist), [SectionList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist) and modify them as per your requirement, as they have more [features and stability](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2017/03/13/better-list-views).

That's why you are getting the above error.

Comment: Accept it if it helps for you, Thanks :)